# Qt project structure - advice needed

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator, project-structure

I'm currently working on a project based on Qt4/QtCreator. I'd like to ask You for advice on how to organize my application.

- There are 3 seperate tools, each has it's own view. All views are integrated in main window as non-closable tabs.  I've prepare 3 views: Tool1View, Tool2View, Tool3View
- Each tool is suppose to perform some task triggered by user actions. But these are not database related operations (list/add/modify...) - at least the user is not going add/modify/list records in gui elements.

I am thinking to implement each tool in 2 classes:

- First class ToolXView implementing the widget and all tasks related to gui changes.
- Second class ToolX implementing application logic. Member functions of this class are triggered by View class. Whenever this class has to update GUI elements it cals specialised functions in View class. So no direct calls to widgets are made from here.

View class and logic class will be linked with each other to allow 2 way communication.

Now I'm wondering if this is  a good way to go. Please advice me based on Your experience.

1. I'm planning to encapsulate pointer to logic class as a property of a view class and pointer to view class as a property of logic class. This way I plan to integrade them.
2. Should I use signals/slots to provide comuncation or just call member functions ?
3. I'll have to store some data in QtSql database. Should I provide a seperate class for database access. Or just implement sepereate member function inside Logic class ?
4. How do You name Your classes. Is this scheme good or should I change it ?

Thanks for help. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [mvc architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is great.

**1 & 2 -** In the link above you will see the UML diagram of a mvc architecture. Regarding it, I would connect view signals to controller methods and then call a view method from controller.

**3 -** Regarding Database access I would add a Data Access part in your architecture  which is specialized to the data access. You can have an interface to define the data access object signature and then implement it in a specialized class for database (So you will be able to change data location without modifying the whole application).

**4 -** You class naming seems good. But I would go further and call classes:

- For view : ClassNameView
- For Controller : ClassNameController
- For DataAccessObject : ClassNameDAO
- Model : ClassName (and IClassName for interface)

Hope that helps

Comment: Do You think that MVC model applies even though there is no database to store data - so there is no DAO and model class ? Should I still call Logic class a controller ?

Comment: DAO is not only used for database access. Your datas can be store in files or even in different database. The DAO is only an abstract layer from which you implement the specialized classes you need.

Comment: But in this project most modules don't store data at all :) That is what I meant. I am familiar with the MVC paradigm and I'm wondering if it fits here.

Comment: In your case the MVC architecture with 3 layers are what you need. The DAO is used in the MVC with 5 layers

Comment: Ok I'm a little confused :) How do I implement controller under qt ? I found an article describing my form as controller, views as qt widgets and a model as class that implements logic. Do You agree with this ?

Comment: View is one or a set of widgets (using QtCreator you can create a designer class [Do not remember the name of the option]). Controller is a simple class with a field that refers to the view